# Simpler way to Print title of a div tag and other contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `div` tag like that:

```
<div class="This is a class" title="Server:http://servername/
Area: PrOD
User: USER NAME"> X</Div>.
```

I want to print title, area and user from the above div tag.

I found couple of threads which are not clear.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the actual div tag in html please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `data-*` attributes and your div would look like this:

```
<div class="myDiv" id="original" title="http://servername" area="PrOD" user="tester"></div>
```

then check this demo which get's all the div's attributes:

```js
$('div').each(function(){
 var attributes = this.attributes;
 $.each(attributes, function(ndx){
     var attrName = attributes[ndx].name;
        var attrVal  = attributes[ndx].value;
        
     // add conditions for certain attribute name;
     console.log(attributes[ndx].name + ' = ' + attributes[ndx].value);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv" id="original" title="http://servername" area="PrOD" user="tester">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, alias.</div>
```

Or with the aid of `data-*` attributes (you will need to update the necessary attributes to start with the data- tag e.g. `data-title`, `data-area`, `data-user`) :

```
<div class="anotherDiv" id="original2" data-title="http://servername" data-area="PrOD" data-user="tester"></div>
```

then check this demo:

```js
var datas = $('div.anotherDiv').data();
$.each(datas, function(ndx){
 console.log(ndx + ' = ' + datas[ndx]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anotherDiv" id="original2" data-title="http://servername" data-area="PrOD" data-user="tester">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, alias.</div>
```

Hope this helps. :)